# Using messages to notify TFrames they should refresh underlying datasets

Tags: delphi, windows-messages, tframe

I am using TFrames to split different parts of a form (visual elements and code) into different units. For example, if my form is an invoice, I have Frame#1 showing the client, invoice date and total amount and Frame#2 containing a list of products with quantity, product name and amount.

Whenever the user is adding/editing/removing a product line, I would like Frame#2 to notify all frames of the change. Frame#1 would then recalculate the total amount.

I would like to use Windows messages to do this but I'm not sure this is possible.

I have defined (in the DataModule that all units use) :

```
Const Message_ProductLineUpdate = WM_USER + 101;
```

Then in Frame#1 I defined my "handler" :

```
procedure RefreshAmount(var Msg:TMessage); message Message_ProductLineUpdate;
```

And in Frame#2, when the change occurs, I do :

```
PostMessage(Application.Handle,Message_ProductLineUpdate,0,0);
```

But RefreshAmount is never called. I first tried :

```
PostMessage(Self.Handle,Message_ProductLineUpdate,0,0);
```

But I guess the message is "dispatched" to the sending frame exclusively. I am also guessing that my handler is only listening to messages posted to its own Handle.

Is it possible to have all frames hooked to the Application's messages ? What is the correct way to deal with that situation ?

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: @UweRaabe Delphi 10.3.2 (VCL exclusively)

Comment: Might be easier in the long run to use LiveBindings instead of rolling your own change notification and synchronization implementation.

Comment: Perhaps using System.Messaging could be an option.

Comment: We use System.Messaging for exactly this. We have several frames, each descended from a base frame, that need to communicate with the application. We use customised messages to move data and requests back and forth. Malcolm Groves wrote a blog entry on this (which is where we got started): http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1372

Comment: Thanks UweRaabe for the System.Messaging that I had not heard of and @PatHeuvel for the link to Malcolm's blog which explains things quite well. I will answer my own question so that the full reference is here.